# How do I access dictionary values with nested for loop?

Tags: list, dictionary, for-loop, nested

I have the following dictionary, and I'd like to output all the items into the terminal sequentially (e.g. Other, Waxing, 20, Manicure, 30, etc...)

```
{'Other': [('Waxing', 20), ('Manicure', 30), ('Extensions', 35)], 'Styling': [('Blow Dry', 15), ('Perm', 25), ('Straightening', 25)], 'Color': [('Full Color', 40), ('Color Retouch', 20), ('Highlights', 30)], 'Haircut': [("Men's Cut", 20), ("Womens's Cut", 20), ("Children's Cut", 10), ('Specialty Cut', 30)]}
```

I currently have the following code:

```
    for key, value in dict.items():
        print(key)
        for i in range(0, len(value)):
            print(value[i])
            for j in range(1):
                print(value[i][j])
```

Which outputs the following:

```
Other
('Waxing', 20)
Waxing
('Manicure', 30)
Manicure
...
```

I'm just confused as to why my last for loop (i.e for loop 'j') isn't printing both 'Waxing' and '20' in the 3rd (and should be 4th) line. I'm under the impression that for loop 'j' should be printing value[i][0] = 'Waxing' & value[i][1] = 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **range()** function in Python returns a sequence of numbers, starting from 0 by default, increments by 1 (by default), and stops before a specified number.

So, if you set the range like this `for j in range(1)`, the loop will stop before it reaches index 1 (read: reaches index 0 only). If you want the loop to reach index 1 as well, you need to set the range to 2, like this `for j in range(2)`.